# Expand primary partition with additional Volume on OVH instance with Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, vps, partition, disk-volume, ovh

I'm trying to setup a VPS on OVH. I've chosen the smallest public cloud general purpose instance and installed Ubuntu 22.04. Here are the system specifications:

8 GB RAM 2 vCore (2.3 GHz) 50 GB NVMe 500 Mbit/s

I will refer to the disk of the instance as /dev/sda

I attached a 300 GB volume, I can manage to mount it as /dev/sdb and create a partition as /dev/sdb1 but this is not the result I wanted.

I'd like to increase the size of /dev/sda to 350 GB, is it possible? How?

Thank you for the kind help :)

I followed the following tutorial and obtained what it describes, that is I mounted the new volume as /dev/sdb1 in /mnt/disk https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-public-cloud-compute-storage-additional-disk?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0050612

What I really want: I want to see the size of my instance partition (/dev/sda) grow to 350 GB

Comment: is lvm involved? and why can't use a second hdd? you can mount any directory to any others?!

Comment: 1) I don't know if lvm is involved
2) I do not have physical access to the machine, as OVH is a cloud computing company offering VPS, dedicated servers and other web services, I cant just use a physical hdd. What I can do, is "attach a Volume", which is what I'm describing
3) this hint gives me some ideas, I will try to mount some directory from /dev/sdb1 onto the "disk space intensive" directories

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @djdomi I figured a solution... I just used the following command and it is good enough for my use case.

```
sudo ln -s /mnt/drive/docker /var/lib/docker
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While the author was using LN instead a native mountpoint, which is not a suggested way.

There are usually also normally the FSTAB which is responsible to do so.

## 1. Mounting /dev/sdb1 native to /var/lib/docker - editing /etc/fstab

```bash
/dev/sdb1    /var/lib/docker    ext4    defaults    0    0
```

> ```
>   This tells the kernel to attach the filesystem found on device (which
>   is of type type) at the directory dir. The option -t type is optional.
>   The mount command is usually able to detect a filesystem. The root
>   permissions are necessary to mount a filesystem by default. See >section
>   "Non-superuser mounts" below for more details. The previous contents
>   (if any) and owner and mode of dir become invisible, and as long as
>   this filesystem remains mounted, the pathname dir refers to the root >of 
>   the filesystem on device.
> ```

## 2. Binding a mounted drive or Folder- editing /etc/fstab

```bash
/dev/sdb1    /var/lib/docker none defaults,bind 0 0
```

> After this call the same contents is accessible in two places. One can also > remount a single file (on a single file).
> This call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem, not possible >submounts. The entire file hierarchy including submounts is attached a second place using

#### References:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount
`man mount` on Debian 12

## 3. What if /dev/sdb1 is actually an USB-Drive that could not be avaible?

```bash
/dev/sdb1    /var/lib/docker none defaults,bind,nofail 0 0
```

> nofail
> Do not report errors for this device if it does not exist.

The Solving is that nofail will be required, but remind that the root device will then be used. If used like this path - that could lead to either not starting the Docker in this question or lead to some wired other problems while the USB Drive is missing.

#### Summary

While the drive can already be mounted and used, you should consider using a bind instead a link.

If the device is not used already, then a mount point is highly recommended.

Remind, that the absence of the device will fail the Daemon, or if new containers will be pushed while the drive is not mounted, the root partion is used either. If you already mounted it to /hdd (i.e.) then use the bind option.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I upvoted it, but as a new user it will not show until I have 15 reputation... also the comment placeholder said to avoid "thank you" as a comment, but instead to suggest improvements... here are my tips: at first your answer was not very clear to me, so maybe a command that starts an editor on the /etc/fstab file would have made your answer more obvious. Also I will go and see what fstab actually is, you could have added a small section explaining it... yet again I just wanted to thank you, you are awesome for helping me, thank you!

Comment: Editing a file should be known under Linux, mostly `nano` is userfriendly and imho `vi` or `vim` has to be learned to use. I assume, since this site is for professional purposes only, at least a bit of knowledge and research. ;) and by the way right know you should be able to do so